# Are there any WYSIWIG editor available for writing GitHub issues?

Tags: github, wysiwyg

I am trying to import my issues from Notion to GitHub but finding the markdown system really hard to write/preview. Writing on markdown is still fine but if I want to see the preview, there's tons of back and forth.

Wondering if someone has solved this issue with an external plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [GitHub Writer](https://github.com/ckeditor/github-writer/), which has a Chrome and Firefox extension.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31551769)